# How to add dynamic contents under those tabs create using renderUI in shinyR application

Tags: shiny

I am building an application in shiny R where in required tabs can be selected by the users and data relevant to those tabs will be displayed under it.

For example, in below sample application, mtcars data in .csv will be accepted as input parameter.User can select required column names in tabs field.Those colmns will be created as tabs.

Now, I want to show data pertaining to that column from .csv in the appropriate tab.Say, data from the column 'mpg' will be shown under 'mpg' tab.

But i am stuck here.Appreciate someone could tell me a way to display data from relevant column under appropriate tab ,dynamically.

Sample codes used is shown below:

`write.csv(mtcars,'mtcars.csv')`

#

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel = headerPanel('data'),
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(fileInput(
            'mtcars', h4('Uplaodmtcardata in csv format')
    ),
    uiOutput('tabnamesui')),
    mainPanel(uiOutput("tabsets"))
   )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
     mtcarsFile <- reactive({input$mtcars})




    xxmtcars <-
            reactive({
                    read.table(
                            file = mtcarsFile()$datapath,
                            sep = ',',
                            header = T,
                            stringsAsFactors = T
                    )
            })

    tabsnames <- reactive({
            names(xxmtcars())
    })

    output$tabnamesui <- renderUI({
            req(mtcarsFile())
            selectInput(
                    'tabnamesui',
                    h5('Tab names'),
                    choices = as.list(tabsnames()),
                    multiple = T
            )


    })
    tabnamesinput <- reactive({
            input$tabnamesui
    })

    output$tabsets <- renderUI({
            req(mtcarsFile())
            tabs <-
                    reactive({
                            lapply(tabnamesinput(), function(x)
                                    tabPanel(title = basename(x), dataTableOutput(x)))
                    })
            do.call(tabsetPanel, c(tabs()))
    })

    output[['mpg']] <-
            renderDataTable(as.data.frame(select(xxmtcars(), mpg)))#HOW TO AVOID THIS HARD CODING..?BASED ON THE TAB NAME DATA FROM RELEVANT COLUMN IN THE CSV TO BE RETURNED.
```

}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))

#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(DT)
ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel = headerPanel('data'),
  sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(fileInput(
    'mtcars', h4('Uplaodmtcardata in csv format')
  ),
  uiOutput('tabnamesui')),
  mainPanel(uiOutput("tabsets"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mtcarsFile <- reactive({input$mtcars})




  xxmtcars <-
    reactive({
      read.table(
        file = mtcarsFile()$datapath,
        sep = ',',
        header = T,
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE
      )
    })

  tabsnames <- reactive({
    names(xxmtcars())
  })

  output$tabnamesui <- renderUI({
    req(mtcarsFile())
    selectInput(
      'tabnamesui',
      h5('Tab names'),
      choices = as.list(tabsnames()),
      multiple = T
    )


  })
  tabnamesinput <- reactive({
    input$tabnamesui
  })

  output$tabsets <- renderUI({
    req(mtcarsFile())

    tabs <-
      reactive({
        lapply(tabnamesinput(), function(x)
          tabPanel(title = basename(x), dataTableOutput(x)))
      })
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(tabs()))
  })


observe(
  lapply(tabnamesinput(), function(x) {
    output[[x]] <- DT::renderDataTable({
t<-as.data.frame(dplyr::select(xxmtcars(), !! sym(x)) )
   print(t)
   datatable(t)

    })
  })
)
}


runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: ,If I could ask one more question, I developed the code to include couple of plots based on your feedback and it is working.But each time i have to subset the data  and i want to avoid that. Say using 'mpg' subsetdata i plotted 2 different types of graphs in 'mpg' tab and i don't want to subset data every time(currently i sub set every time) when i draw the plot.For all calculations in one tab, i would like to subset the data only once.
Sorry to bother you.Please help.

Comment: Please raise it as a separate question.